# How do I prove that if $2\nmid n$ then $2|(n+1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'd like to prove a very simple fact, but it's stumping me: namely, that if $2 \nmid n$ then $2\mid(n+1)$.

How would this usually be done?

Comment: what can you use?

Comment: Presumably you have $n$ as an integer.  Break it into cases.  Either $n$ is even or $n$ is odd.  If $2\not\mid n$ then what does that imply?

Comment: If $n \not\equiv 0 (mod2)$, then $n+1 \not\equiv 1 (mod2)$, so we must have $n+1 \equiv 0 (mod2)$

Comment: @JMoravitz Say that I don't know that numbers are either even or odd

Comment: @Leafar Nice -- very nice. Would you like to write that up as the answer?

Comment: @user89 $n+1\not\equiv 1\pmod{2}\Rightarrow n+1\equiv 0\pmod{2}$ is equivalent to stating that all numbers are either even or odd.  If you say you cannot use that line of logic, then this is equally invalid.

Comment: Well, in my answer I don't care about even or odd numbers. In this particular implication, I only state that if something $mod2$ is not $1$, then it's $0$.

Comment: @user89 remember that definition of even number is $n$ is even if $n=2m$ for some integer $m$ (ie 2 divides $n$) thus you do know if its even or odd by definition of even or odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n \not\equiv 0 \pmod2$, then $n+1 \not\equiv 1 \pmod2$, so we must have $n+1 \equiv 0 \pmod2$

Comment: Please look at my edits to your answer.  \pmod 2 does it.  (If there's more than one character, you need curly braces, as in \pmod{23}. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5):

If $2 \nmid  n$ means $n$ is odd i.e. $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$, therefore $n+1=2k+2=2(k+1) \implies 2 \mid (n+1)$

Answer (score 5):

by division algorithm $n=2q+r$ where $r$ can only be $1$.  so $n+1$ = $2q+2$

Comment: How do I prove that $r$ can only be 1?

Comment: must be less than $2$ and greater than $0$ by division alg.

Answer (score 0):

If 2 does not divide $n$ then $n$ is must be odd thus $n+1$ must be even thus by definition of even 2 must divide $n+1$